# How to set a <div> inside of a <p>?

Tags: html, css

I want to use a `<div>` inside a `<p>` so that when I render the code, it should print showing the div. Ex: `<p> this is a <div></div> </p>` Output: `this is a <div><div/>`

I've tried the code below, but whenever I input any <> in the field, it ignores it and uses it to style the content.

```
<input type="text" id="body_text" value="" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="title_text" value="" />
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="global-title"></p>
<p id="global-body"></p>

<script>
  // Here the value is stored in new variable x
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("title_text").value;
    document.getElementById("global-title").innerHTML = x;
    var y = document.getElementById("body_text").value;
    document.getElementById("global-body").innerHTML = y;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You **dont**.... the browser will close the `p` automatically. A div inside a `p` is invalid HTML

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what you want to do. Are you trying to show the angle brackets to the reader?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, I am trying to show the angle brackets with the div inside of it

Comment: @Shagufta that's exactly what I've done below.

Comment: If you want the angle brackets to become human-text, then HTML-encode them as `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.innerText` instead of `.innerHTML`

```js
// Here the value is stored in new variable x
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("title_text").value;
    document.getElementById("global-title").innerText = x;
    var y = document.getElementById("body_text").value;
    document.getElementById("global-body").innerText = y;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="body_text" value="" />
<br />
<input type="text" id="title_text" value="" />
<br />
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="global-title"></p>
<p id="global-body"></p>
```